# ADB2C - How to persist logged in status in .NET Core webapp after browser closed

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

I am using ADB2C (IEF Custom policies and User Flows) to implement signin on a .NET Core WebApp using OpenID (OIDC).

When users login to my app, I am able to check their logged in status using the standard

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated`

However, if I close my browser and come back to the app after some time, this logged in status of the user is lost UNTIL I visit the login policy, at which point it auto logs me in.

Is there a simple way to persist the authentication status longer in the cookie so that this step is not needed? I have read in places that there is a way to hold it for 90 days but cant find much info on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

In B2C The maximum cookie session time you can configure is `1440 Minutes` For Configuring session behavior please go through the document [User flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior#session-behavior-properties) and [Custom policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-behavior-custom-policy#session-behavior-properties).

```
Web app session lifetime (minutes) - The lifetime of Azure AD B2C's session cookie stored on the user's browser upon successful authentication.
•   Default = 1440 minutes.
•   Minimum (inclusive) = 15 minutes.
•   Maximum (inclusive) = 1440 minutes.
```

There is a `Keep me signed-in` feature which extends the session life time through the use of a persistent cookie. The session remains active after the user closes and reopens the browser. The session is revoked only when a user signs out. The Keep me signed-in feature only applies to sign-in with local accounts. Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-policy-keep-me-signed-in) for more information.

Regarding the Persistent tokens lifetime of 90 days it is related to the [Azure AD SSO session tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#single-sign-on-session-tokens) for that configuration you can refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#example-manage-an-organizations-default-policy)

Comment: I am using a custom IEF policy using a SelfAsserted flow (local accounts) and I have been advised that KMSI does not work with this out of the box. Is there a way to configure this on my application to somehow force this cookie?

Comment: Yes until the KMSI box is not checked it wont work. once we close my browser the cookie information will be lost.

Comment: i was mentioning about KMSI checkbox

Comment: Please let us know if this answer was helpful to you. If so, please remember to mark it as the answer using the check mark so that others in the community with similar questions can more easily find a solution. Also, Please spare few mins to let us know how we did using this link <https://microsoft.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9?Q_DL=Fa5t8dkcKtAi0la_6Sh1E5ZBWke4wO9_MLRP_39H7sUsONtGBE9f&Q_CHL=gl
>